# How to properly update an Object in the back-end from the front-end using Spring and ThymeLeaf?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm getting trouble trying to update my Object in the back-end via a front-end template.

This is my **template**, it uses ThymeLeaf

```
    <form id="formUpdate" method="put">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <h2> Modificar Gustos</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <label for="selectGusto">Nombre del gusto a cambiar</label>
            <select name="gustos" id="selectGusto">
                <option value="-1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Lista de Gustos</option>
                <option th:each="gusto : ${gustos}" th:text="${gusto.nombre}" th:value="${gusto.id}"> </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <label for="newName">Nuevo Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="newName" id="newName" />
        <div class="row">
            <label for="selectCat">Elegir nueva Categoria</label>
                <select name="newCat" id="selectCat">
                    <option value="-1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Nueva Categoria</option>
                    <option value="Dulces de Leche">Dulce de Leche</option>
                    <option value="Cremas">Cremas</option>
                    <option value="Chocolates">Chocolates</option>
                    <option value="Frutales">Frutales</option>
                </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="btn-submit" class="button">Modificar</button>
    </form>
```

This is my **JS** linked to the template:

```
 var newCatId;
   var idGusto;
   var newName;

   $('#selectCat').on('change', () => {
        var value = $('#selectCat').val();
        if(value === "Dulces de Leche") {
            newCatId = 1;
        }
        else if(value === "Cremas") {
            newCatId = 2;
        }
        else if(value === "Chocolates") {
            newCatId = 3;
        }
        if(value === "Frutales") {
            newCatId = 4;
        }

        console.log('newCatId: ' + newCatId);
        console.log('idGusto ' + idGusto);
        console.log('newName: ' + newName);
 });

    $('#selectGusto').on('change', function() {
    idGusto = $(this).val();
  });

    newName = $('#newName').val();

 $('#btn-submit').on('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = idGusto + " '/edit' + '/' "+ newName + '/' + newCatId;
    $('#formUpdate').attr('action', url);
 });
```

And this is the Spring **controller** that should handle the request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/gustos/{id}/edit/{newName}/{newIdCat}")
public String updateGustoById(@PathVariable("id") int id, @PathVariable("newIdCat") int newIdCat, @PathVariable("newName") String newName){
    Gusto gusto = gustoService.findGustoById(id);
    gusto.setNombre(newName);
    gusto.setIdCategoria(newIdCat);
    gustoService.update(gusto);
    return "redirect:/gustos/edit";
}
```

Ok !! This code doesn't breaks anywhere but when I click on the submit button the variables in the JS travel in the URL as a Query String, that's not what I want to.

Example of my URL after clicking the form's submit button:

```
http://localhost:8080/gustos/edit?gustos=106&newName=Dulce+de+Leche+Granizado&newCat=Dulces+de+Leche
```

This is my first time making a Spring App!

My question is, how can I send the information to the controller in the right way? How do people normally update an Object if is not like this? :(

**EDIT**: The expected values are OK, that means the JS is working OK. The problem is sending the values to the back-end !! The form is sending them as a Query String and that's not what I need, neither the assigned values on the Query String are fine

Comment: I don't see why javascript is used at all - why not just let the form be naturally POSTed?

Comment: Don't know why ... hahaha ... I'll try that now ... I thought I'd must do it with a PUT method and the form didn't accepted the put, then changed ... you know how it is ... I'll try Aravind's solution now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Your Scenario, Your trying to form path param URL

1.Instead of path params you can directly specify the action attribute in form element

```
<form id="formUpdate" method="GET" action="http://localhost:8080/gustos/edit">
```

method attribute can be **GET** or **POST** according to your need.

And  newCat Select box like

```
 <select name="newCat" id="selectCat">
        <option value="-1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Nueva Categoria</option>
        <option value="1">Dulce de Leche</option>
        <option value="2">Cremas</option>
        <option value="3">Chocolates</option>
        <option value="4">Frutales</option>
 </select>
```

In Backend you can use **@RequestParam** to get paramter values

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/gustos/edit")
public String updateGustoById(@RequestParam(value="gustos") int id, @RequestParam(value="newCat") 
int newIdCat, @RequestParam(value="newName") String newName)
{
  Gusto gusto = gustoService.findGustoById(id);
  gusto.setNombre(newName);
  gusto.setIdCategoria(newIdCat);
  gustoService.update(gusto);
  return "redirect:/gustos/edit";
}
```

2.Another approach, Construct a **JSON** string with **form field values** (like you did for path params), While Submitting the form send this JSON string to back end through **ajax call**.
On your service layer keep this JSON String as **Java beans** (Spring Boot bind JSON values with the bean fields through **@RequestBody** annotation, if bean structure matched with the JSON).

Comment: This might work !! Thanks brother ... I'll try it out

Comment: This worked perfectly and learned about the @RequestParam (I didn't knew it existed) ! Thanks you and greetings from Argentina :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `th:object` in your form. This creates an object of a given type instantly when you submit your form. So, let's say your object is of type Gusto. If you want to create a new entity from scratch, you could add this method in your controller that will return a new entity of type Gusto.

**New Model Attribute**

```
// In order to use th:object in a form, we must be able to map a new entity to that form.
// In this case we return a Gusto entity.
@ModelAttribute(value = "newGusto")
public Gusto newGusto() {return new Gusto();}
```

**Form**

So now, you can use this entity in a form using `th:object="${newGusto}"`. This will create a new entity for you, which you might mapped fields to it.

In order to do so you would need to add following one elements to your form.

```
<form action="/gustos/edit/" id="formUpdate" method="put" th:object="${newGusto}">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
            <h2> Modificar Gustos</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="selectGusto">Nombre del gusto a cambiar</label>
        <select th:field="*{id}" name="gustos" id="selectGusto">
            <option value="-1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Lista de Gustos</option>
            <option th:each="gusto : ${gustos}" th:text="${gusto.nombre}" th:value="${gusto.id}"> </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <label for="newName">Nuevo Nombre</label>
    <input th:field=*{nombre} type="text" name="newName" id="newName" />
    <div class="row">
        <label for="selectCat">Elegir nueva Categoria</label>
            <select th:field="*{categoria} name="newCat" id="selectCat">
                <option value="-1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Nueva Categoria</option>
                <option value="Dulces de Leche">Dulce de Leche</option>
                <option value="Cremas">Cremas</option>
                <option value="Chocolates">Chocolates</option>
                <option value="Frutales">Frutales</option>
            </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="btn-submit" class="button">Modificar</button>
</form>
```

The only difference you will find with your current code, is the added `th:field` elements in your selects and inputs and the `th:object`. Each one of these inputs and selects, will automatically mapped each field to the new entity you just created in your form.

**Controller**

Now for your controller you would need to change it for the following.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/gustos/edit/")
public String updateGusto(@ModelAttribute("newGusto") Gusto gustoToUpdate){
    Gusto gusto = gustoService.findGustoById(gustoToUpdate.getId());
    gusto.setNombre(gustoToUpdate.getNombre());
    gusto.setIdCategoria(gustoToUpdate.getCategoria());
    gustoService.update(gusto);
    return "redirect:/gustos/edit";
}
```

Of course, in your case, it is important that you change your `jquery`. We don't want to change the URL now. We just want to submit the form. So the following code, would have to be removed.

```
$('#btn-submit').on('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = idGusto + " '/edit' + '/' "+ newName + '/' + newCatId;
    $('#formUpdate').attr('action', url);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Alain, I used a different solution this time cause it seemed easier than the object binding ! Just got the params with the @RequestParam ... didn't knew I could do that :) Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: No problem! It is always good to more approaches to a problem :)